# Wordpress is redirecting me to homepage

Tags: plugins, php, posts

When i click on add new post/pages, Wordpress is redirecting to the homepage.
is anyone facing with the same issue? or have any solution for this issue.
Thank you

Comment: First, check the obvious: (1) is your site url correct (settings)? (2, if on apache) Is the rewritebase in .htaccess correct? (3) do you have redirect plugins active? (4) do you have any rewrite rules in your webserver software active? E.g. for non-www or non-ssl?

Comment: @JosFaber i have checked:(1)  site url is correct. (2). i am not using any redirection plugin. (3). i dont know how to check the rewritebase in .htaccess correct or not.

Comment: If you did not create the htaccess yourself then it’s probably ok. If you have plugins installed, you can disable them all. If the problem then disappears, enable them one by one to find out which one potentially causes the problem.

Comment: I have deactivated them. still i am facing same problem. the rewritebase in .htaccess is also correct. i dont know what is wrong

Comment: Just to be sure; clear browser cache. If that not helps, could you try to fix the site url by using these two defines in `wp-config.php`? `define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://example.com' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com' );` (ofcourse substituting example.com with your wordpress url)

Comment: @JosFaber this is not working. "wp-admin/post-new.php", this url is redirected to homepage.

Comment: Did you define the site url with those two defines? And did you clear browser cache?

Comment: Yes. I have pasted those defines at the top of wp-config.php

Comment: I'm sorry, this is as far as I can get without owning the code and direct access to it.

Comment: no problem @JosFaber. Thank you so much for helping.

Comment: @JosFaber. My website was infected. Now I have the path of the infected files, but I'm not able to recognize the infected code line.

Comment: What do you mean by "infected"? Someone inserted code? How do you know? Do you have a backup? I suggest resetting the site to the latest backup before the infection. Because even if you found some weird line of code, how would you know if that was the only one?

Comment: This is happening because your website contain malware code.
follow these step:
1. contact with your hosting provider.
2. ask them to scan your website.
3. they will provide a file containing paths of the infected file/code.
4. delete the malware code/files.

my problem was by following these steps.

Comment: @JosFaber there were some extra files in files

Comment: You could install mamp or xampp and setup your site localy, to see if there is any difference. To be honest, I would not continue from an infected site, but instead setup a complete new one and transfer data piece by piece. Just to be sure there is nothing left..